# Scrumptious Application doesn't works in Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am following the exact tutorial from the `Facebook Developers` page and installed `Scrumptious application` on the android phone that comes with `Facebook Android SDK 3.0`. Whenever I pass my username and password to the Facebook login page. I always get the below `NPE`.

> And strange thing is whenever I run the same application on the
>   emulator, it is working fine.
>
> And also if I try to run the same
>   application on the phone but without Facebook Application installed,
>   then Scrumptious app works fine.

I have also tried with other Facebook SDK examples as well. Most of them are failing with same NPE.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.facebook.scrumptious/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3182)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.facebook.NativeProtocol.isServiceDisabledResult20121101(NativeProtocol.java:238)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaLoginDialogAuthHandler.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:587)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:142)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:134)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
02-02 12:49:25.520: E/AndroidRuntime(5219): ... 11 more
```

And also this error as well-

```
03-23 19:08:28.820: E/AndroidRuntime(28599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.platform.PlatformWrapperActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am working on Android SDK 3.0

Has anyone tried Facebook Sample Example on the phone not on the emulator? And please let me know if anyone was able to run the sample example on the phone itself.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Trace down the NPE and fix it. Find out what's null and why.

Comment: @TechGeeky I got this same crash report from google play. I cannot reproduce this issue and I have never encountered this issue while developing the app. Have you found a solution for this.

Comment: @glo upgrade facebook sdk..